# How would I filter a collection by translated properties?

Tags: filter, collections, translation, shopware, twig-extension

The following function within the `EntityCollection` class can be used for filtering a collection based on properties:

```
public function filterByProperty(string $property, $value)
{
    return $this->filter(
        static function (Entity $struct) use ($property, $value) {
            return $struct->get($property) === $value;
        }
    );
}
```

How can I use this function to filter based on translated fields? I've created a twig extension which now does it for me, but I'd rather use the default function. This is my custom twig extension:

```
public function filterByTranslatedProperty(EntityCollection $entityCollection, string $property, $value): EntityCollection
{
    return $entityCollection->filter(
        static function (Entity $struct) use ($property, $value) {
            return $struct->getTranslation($property) === $value;
        }
    );
}
```